# Разница между статическими методами и методами экземпляра

Tags: java

Существует какой-то класс для работы с контекстом.

```
public class UserContextManager {

    private static UserContext init() {
        UserContext context = new UserContext();
        //thread safe логика инициалзации без вызовов сторонних сервисов и т.д.

        return context;
    }

    public UserContext handleAutorizeRequest() {
        UserContext context = init();

        //business logic
    }
}
```

При добавлении модификатора `static` в методе `init()` cуществует ли выйгрыш ?

1. по памяти
2. по скорости работы
3. по каким-то еще критериям (размещение обьектов внутри VM?)

Comment: Это всё равно, что спрашивать «что лучше, int или String?». Если нужен int, используйте int, а если нужен String, используйте String. То же и здесь: если метод есть метод экземпляра, имеет смысл в контексте конкретного экземпляра, то используйте instance-метод. Если метод имеет смысл в контексте всего класса, но не конкретного экземпляра, делайте статический метод.

Comment: Выигрыш одной наносекунды не стоит сломанной семантики.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне в ответ на "сломанную семантику" говорят, что будет выйрыш ибо не надо хранить по ментоду на каждый экземпляр, а будет один статический. Собсвенно я и задал вопрос таким образом, чтобы можно количественно ответить и привести агрументы.

Comment: Выигрыш будет также, если отказаться от классов и писать всё в одном методе. Но так не делают, потому что выигрыш не стоит того.

Comment: "ибо не надо хранить по ментоду на каждый ..." - не слушайте их

Comment: @Igor  всетаки я работаю в команде и я не могу игнорировать других членов. Соответсвенно прошу аргументации.

Comment: @bbdMinimbl члены не понимают, о чем они говорят. Это просто не так. Читайте им вслух учебник по Джаве.

Comment: Но если будет по одному описанию класса для static и instance (насколько я понимаю так и есть), то тогда получается, что у static выйгрыш ?

Comment: @bbdMinimbl что есть - "одно описание класса"?

Comment: имею ввиду информацию по классу (описание класса?), которая в PermGen грузилась (до java8)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64181/discussion-between-bbdminimbl-and-igor).